# <img /> inside <a> and SRC

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code for showing image inside any tag:

```
var imgs = $(this).find("p").attr("rel");
$('.hLeft img').attr("src", imgs);
```

Markup:

```
<div class="hLeft">
    <h2></h2>
    <a href="" class="mn">
    </a>
    <img src="" />        
</div>
```

But when I insert `<img>` inside a, my script not working.

```
$('.mn img').attr("src", imgs);
```

Markup:

```
 <div class="hLeft">
    <h2></h2>
    <a href="" class="mn">
        <img src="" /> 
    </a>     
</div>
```

Why the `$('.mn img').attr("src", imgs);` not working with a tag?

Comment: Why isn't it working? What happens?

Comment: What selector is 'this' refering to in this statement: var imgs = $(this).find("p").attr("rel");
??

Comment: @Nick Craver, nothing happens. With <div> tag, I can see <img src="blah blah"> inside div. But with a, the image does not appear inside a.

Comment: @TheNone - there might be some invalid markup going on here, can you post an actual example block?

Comment: Make a small version of your code on http://jsbin.com/

Comment: @ben; $('.rUl li').click(function(){});. $(this) is $('.rUl li')

Comment: @TheNone - I meant the HTML markup :)

Comment: @Nick Craver , Im sorry, I have edited :)

Comment: You should tidy up your JavaScript. It is very unreadable and has duplicate code. For example, you store `$(this)` in `$li`, but you continue using `$(this)`. Also `$('p', $li).attr("rel");` and `$(this).find("p").attr("rel");` do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @RoToRa ; "$(this). Also $('p', $li).attr("rel"); and $(this).find("p").attr("rel");" I know!! I have tried every thing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the img is over written by this line:

```
$("a", $hleft).html(mansetText);
```

Comment: The image doesnot appear with deleting the $("h2", $hleft).html(mansetTitle);

Comment: user239427 is talking about "$("a", $hleft).html(mansetText);" and not "$("h2", $hleft).html(mansetTitle);"

Answer (score 0):

I think it deals with the css properties of class `mn`. `div` are displayed as block by default which is not the case for `a`. Try to add `display:block;` in the `mn` class to see the result.